# Is the connection pool shared between master and slave servers in JBoss?

Tags: java, server, jboss, jboss6.x, application-server

If we provide the maximum pool size field for a connection on the master server, is the pool shared between all master and slave servers, or is a new pool created for each slave server?

Answer (score 0):

The (cluster) nodes will not share connection pools between instances at all, since this does not make sense.

You can set a configuration value in domain mode for a single server instance or for a configuration shared per group of servers.

Please refer the [JBoss Domain Mode Configuration docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Domain+Setup).

Comment: I wanted to know specifically about db pool size property. From the console, I can configure pool size (let's say 20) of a db source, for the master. You mean to say that for *each* slave and master server, 20 connections will be reserved?

Comment: Yes. I corrected the link pointing to the right documentation regarding domain mode and configuration of JBoss groups.